# Why is my Select Statement not working properly?

Tags: php, sql, select

I am trying to select rows in my table sql. I have done this many times and for this instant it wouldn't work.

Displaying the variable $id, displays correct value, which means it receives a correct value from $_POST however after using it on Select Statement and using mysql_fetch_array, nothing displays.

**my code**

```
$id=$_POST['idsend'];
$edit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id= '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($edit);
echo 'ID= '.$id; ---------> This one displays properly
echo 'ID= '.$fetch['id']; --------> displays nothing
```

Please help me find out what's wrong. Hehe thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Remove single quotes from `$id`.

Comment: im going to try that, but i have include('connect-db.php'); included in the same php file. And that was just enough to do it on my other php files where I executed a select statement. hehe

Comment: @Rikesh removing the single quotes. Nothing happened. Hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found out what's wrong. I apologize for disturbing everyone. I have realized what's wrong in my code and you won't find it on the code I posted in my question.

Carelessness again is the cause for all these. :) hehe

**This is where the error is coming from**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="idsend" value="' . $row['id'] . '"/>
```

*I have assigned a variable on a value with extra spaces/character? So the code must look like this.*

```
<input type="hidden" name="idsend" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
```

It must be assigned properly to work smoothly with the select statement.
I guess echo-ing the values isn't enough to see if there's something wrong.

Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It would be safer to use PDO, to prevent SQL Injection (I made a PDO example of your query):

```
// it's better to put the following lines into a configuration file!
$host = "enter hostname here";
$dbname = "enter dbname here";
$username = "enter db username here";
$password = "enter db password here";
// setup a PDO connection (needs some error handling)
$db_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);  
// prepare and execute query
$q_handle = $db_handle->prepare("select * from students where id = ?");
$id = $_POST["idsend"];
$q_handle->bindParam(1, $id);
$q_handle->execute();
// get stuff from array
$arr = $q_handle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $arr["id"];
```

Comment: thank you sir! But I have found out what's wrong and I have just posted it. Still thank you :) It was coming from a very simple but crucial mistake in assigning values. hehe

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use [mysql_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions anymore.

You code fails because `mysql_fetch_array()` only returns a resource, you need to loop over it to get the actual result.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $edit ) ) {
    printf( 'ID: %s', $row['id'] );
}
```

Comment: okay, im going to try that. But that same code worked fine on a separate php file.